# Pull Button for git disabled in VisualStudio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, git-pull, pull

I'm using VisualStudio 2013 Update 4 and have git for Windows installed.
I have local git repository and my project is linked to. I can push unsynced commits to remote repository in the IDE, but button for pull and fetch are disabled.

In git bash i can pull (or fetch) and then back in VS i get an unsynced commitment for "merge" and can push it (Looks strange to me).

Can i integrate pull/fetch from remote repository without TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question?
You want to perform git pull/fetch outside of VS editor.

if your git path is set in your environment path variable, then post navigating to your local .git repository directory via command prompt/powershell you should be able to run "git pull" and it should work.
The git path is defaulted to "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\cmd"

Comment: I do it in git bash (not in PowerShell) and that works. But i want it to run in VS-IDE. There ( in the team-explorer) the Buttons for Pull and fetch are disabled. the path is set (push works),

Comment: A clarifying question. The branch on which you are trying to perform Pull/Fetch has an upstream branch configured?

Comment: That is a good question. where can i see it? My config file in git looks like:[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
 url = //myServer/myShare/myProject
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
[gui]
 wmstate = normal
 geometry = 1333x742+113+26 376 192
[remote "xy_github"]
 url = git@git.anyother.selfhost.eu:myCompany/prototype.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/xy_github/*

Comment: I think that IS the problem, but where can i do that? how do i configure an upstream branch, because i CAN pull in git Bash - but not in VS.

Comment: Have you tried setting up an upstream branch on the bash prompt for your local branch.

git branch -u origin/branchname

Are you sure you are able to pull all the changes from the remote master branch into your local branch using just "git pull", or are you doing git pull origin master?

Comment: If i have no current temporary branch i use git pull origin master. And in VS i am on the master branch.

Comment: Its weird. Generally master branch has upstream tracking branch origin\master

"git status -sb"  

when you are you master branch on the bash prompt run the command  (without double quotes) and check the remote branch.

Comment: Did that. it says: ## master then some files with "M" (modified?) and some files wih "??" (excluded files)  Can i  set -u with any command (without making a new branche?)

Comment: It shoudl ideally say "## master...origin/master" which shows the tracking branch. So it means that your local master branch is not tracked.

run the first command I sent "git branch -u origin\master" and all should be good from within VS as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "git branch -u" was the key :-)

Comment: Sorry, i can't vote or push you up, but i'm very happy about your help

Comment: 2021: remote config options have moved a lot in VS. Also, VS grays out the pull option if you're already up to date with your remote.