# How come the git Pull button in Visual Studio is disabled?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

[image]

it didn't happen before, but it happened to me today.
What are the possible cause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull Button for git disabled in VisualStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099585/pull-button-for-git-disabled-in-visualstudio)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your branch may have an upstream tracking branch.

Try running "git status -sb" when you are on the branch in the command prompt- if it only shows "## <branch_name>" your local branch is not tracked. It would show "## master...origin/<branch_name>" if it were. In this case running "git branch -u origin/<branch_name>" in the command prompt should fix your issue.

Comment: git branch -u origin/<branch_name> this worked, Thanks

Comment: This fix works, but does anyone knows why the tracking is "lost" in the first place?
I'm just doing "normal" git stuff via VS, and hardly ever messing around with command line git commands. Yet this very annoying and disrupting thing happens every now and then for no apparent reason...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to perform for a particular branch that was only local and fulfilled above conditions (as per @amateur's answer) this command:

```
git push -u <remoteRepoName>
```

Then the local branch that was not pushable in Visual Studio menus (disabled Push button) started to appear as a standard branch. I do not know why this sometimes happens. But this solves the consequences.